# Python - How to handle exception while iterating through list?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium library and trying to iterate through list of items look them up on web and while my loop is working when item are found I am having hard time handling the exception when item is not find on the web page. For this instance I know that if the item is not found the page will show " No Results For" within span to which I can access with:

```
browser.find_by_xpath('(.//span[@class = "a-size-medium a-color-base"])[1]')[0].text
```

Now the problem is that this span only appear when item loop is searching is not found.  So I tried this logic, if this span doesn't exist than it means item is found so execute rest of the loop, if the the span does exist and is equal to " No Results For", then go and search for next item. Here is my code:

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
for i in lookup_list:
    start_url = f"https://www.amazon.com/s?k=" + i +"&ref=nb_sb_noss_1"
    browser.visit(start_url)
    if browser.find_by_xpath('(.//span[@class = "a-size-medium a-color-base"])[1]') is not None :
    #browser.find_by_xpath("//a[@class='a-size-medium a-color-base']"):
        item = browser.find_by_xpath("//a[@class='a-link-normal']")
        item.click()
        html = browser.html
        soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
        collection_dict ={
            'PART_NUMBER': getmodel(soup),
            'DIMENSIONS': getdim(soup),
            'IMAGE_LINK': getImage(soup)        
        }
    elif browser.find_by_xpath('(.//span[@class = "a-size-medium a-color-base"])[1]')[0].text != 'No results for':
        continue
    data = data.append(collection_dict, ignore_index=True)
```

The error I am getting is:

> AttributeError: 'ElementList' object has no attribute 'click'

I do understand that the error I am getting is because I cant access attribute click since it the list has multiple items and therefore i cant click on all of them. But what im trying to do is to avoid even trying to access it if the page showes that the item is not found, i want the script to simply go to next item and search.
How do I modify this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a `try: except:` block, with a `pass` inside of the `except`

Comment: In the beginning you could add something like "I am using Selenium to". That prevents people from wondering what lib you used until the ending tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a try-except with a pass is what you want in this situation, like @JammyDodger said. Although using this typically isn't a good sign because you don't want to simply ignore errors most of the time. `pass` will simply ignore the error and continue the rest of the loop.

```py
try:
    item.click()
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

In order to skip to the next iteration of the loop, you may want to use the `continue` keyword.

```py
try:
    item.click()
except AttributeError:
    continue
```

Comment: @Alect B. I see what you saying about ignoring the error but in this particular case your solution works for what i need. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Slavisha84 No problem, glad I could help!